# how to call a parameter from all structs in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, return

In one class named DataService.swift I have created an array of struct's as follows...

```
class DataService {
   static let instance = DataService()

   private let bicepWorkouts = [
            Workout(title: "Bicep Machine", imageName: "gloves.png", timeLength: "2:43", videoCode: "_kAlQ5Bh5aY", level: "Beginner", type: "Strength", likes: "5 Likes"),
            Workout(title: "Bicep Curl", imageName: "sixplates.png", timeLength: "1:44", videoCode: "_kAlQ5Bh5aY", level: "Beginner", type: "Strength", likes: "5 Likes")
        ]

    func getBicepWorkouts() -> [Workout] {
        return bicepWorkouts
    }
}
```

I want to call the Workout videoCode: "_kAlQ5Bh5aY" from each struct in the bicepWorkout array to a different class. 
Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 let work1 = DataService.instance.bicepWorkouts[0]
 print("\(work1.videoCode)")
```

Comment: This has done the trick! Just a note for anyone else with this issue, the private needed to be removed also.